# Text sharpness on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, web-applications

I made a webapp, which works perfectly fine on most mobiles. Only sometimes on my iPhone 5s (And I heard from other people on other iOS devices aswell) the text gets blurry. This occurs sometimes on the same pages where it didn't happen before and vica versa.

Can't seem to find any explanation about this on the internet.

Anyone know what can make this occur?

Screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check for the similiar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537762/ipad-2-safari-shows-pixellated-html-text-and-images). Hope it will help you. Let me know how it work for you.